# Wordpress Site in Multiple Languages

Tags: plugins, multi-language, language

How can wordpress site have multiple languages options?
I would like to have my wordpress site in 3 different languages?
How can I do that? Is there any plugin or widget I can use for that purpose?

Comment: Search on WordPress plugins respiratory for multi language plugins. Plugin recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: There is no "respiratory" plugin on Wordpress plugins.
Are you sure that's the correct name?

Comment: I meant search `multi language plugins` here in [WordPress Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/)

Comment: and by the way, the question was general - I do not know ho and if it is even possible to add multilingual option to a wordpress site. If I can do it with a plugin - great! If not - is there more elegant solution? How people do it in most cases? What's the best practice for multilingual support? - That was the question.

Comment: Have you tried searching on Google for this. The first result is for [Multilingual WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress). This article shows how you can create a multi language WordPress website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best free plugin for your goal is Polylang:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang

Not so great but still easy to use is mqTranslate, which is a fork of the pretty popular qTranslate:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/mqtranslate/

A good popular (but paid) one is WPML:

https://wpml.org

Comment: Thx for your reply! I have installed Polylang, and I have two questions. First, since I already made a site in English, after installing the plugin I do not see any of the pages I made. How can I use what I already made and integrate it into ENGLISH languge item, so to say? Second is regarding the icons - how can I put on the frontend the language flags and language names, so that a user can click on them and change languages?

Comment: Ok - I think I found the answer to the first question - in seetings set the defaul language to english.
CAn you please help me with the second question?

Comment: And third question is - I was just wondering what happens with blog posts? For ecample when I want to publish a blog post say in English - will this blog post only be seen when English is selected as prefered language, or it will always be shown, no matter what language is selected?

Comment: There must be a widget in Appearance -> Widgets, that is called something like "language switcher" or something, that will let you change the language in the front end. I'm not sure if this is available, but probably there is also an option in the settings to add a language switcher in the main menu.

On the third question - posts are translated the same way as pages, so it won't be any different. In the settings you select the behavior of single-language pages or posts.

You'll find more help (and info) on the plugin support  forum ;)

Comment: Great advices! Thank you very much.
One more question - is the best practice to create multiple menus - each menu corresponds to different language, and than do the translation? And is it possible to structure the language switcher - in the sense of moving the items, align them not one beneath the other, but next to other, center the language items, and similar changes?

Comment: Using "order" in the languages settings you can define which is the first one and which language is second in the list of the switcher.

Polylang creates different menu locations for each language, so yes - you need a separate list of items for each language.

Changes of the structure you can do by applying some CSS, there ain't easier way.